# How can I create a planar graph? (graph based method )

Tags: c++, graph

Creating a planar graph using a graph based method is a my homework.

graph based method is to maxmize weight between departments.

The steps of the graph method

- Step 1: Select a department pair with largest weight
- Step 2: Select a third department based on the sum of the weights with
  the two departments selected
- Step 3: Select next unselected department to enter by evaluating the sum  of weights and place the department on the face of the graph
- Step 4: counting the step3 untill all deapartments are selected

I've finished Step3.

this is a relation chart to create planrgraph.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4BnL.jpg)

My code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= in_step4_1.size() - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= in_step4_1.size() - 1; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k <= in_step4_1.size() - 1; k++)
        {
            if ((in_step4_1[i] < in_step4_1[j]) && (in_step4_1[j] < in_step4_1[k]) && (in_step4_1[j] < in_step4_1[k]))
            {
                cout << "(" << in_step4_1[i] << "," << in_step4_1[j] << "," << in_step4_1[k] << ")";
                in_step4[count].push_back(in_step4_1[i]);
                in_step4[count].push_back(in_step4_1[j]);
                in_step4[count].push_back(in_step4_1[k]);

                if (++count % 4 == 0) cout << endl;

            }
        }
    }
}
n=count;
cout << endl;
}
```

I want to find only possible combinations, not all combinations.

Answer (score 0):

> Step 1 : Select a department pair with largest weight

Simply sort your container using a sorting algorithm like `std::sort`:

```
std::sort(std::begin(in_step4_1), std::end(in_step4_1));
// largest weight is in_step4_1[in_step4_1.size() - 1]
```

Comment: I do not think I can explain well.
The above code is the code that creates the combination after the sort is done.
What I'm wondering is that the condition of the planar graph is how all the nodes are triangulated, and how they make it a triangle.
This is because the triangles are damaged if I code them.